# How to Write subquery in sql to map dictionary values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I have a dictionary, which maps integers to string and another table which stores the relationship between integers:

```
    Dictionary (id, stringvalue)
    1      Where
    2      are you
    3      going
    4      This 
    5      is
    6      stackoverflow

   Table(col1, col2, col3)
   Col1    col2     col3
   1       2        3
   4       5        6
```

The steps to query the two tables are the following:

```
1. Given string map them to ids using dictionary
2. Given strings map them to corresponding column using Table, which gives an integer
3. Given ids which we got from step1 map them again to string and present the result to the user?
```

Now in order to find out what is the next column value after "Where are", I can query in the following form:

```
   select d3.stringvalue from dictionary d1, dictionary d2, dictionary d3, Table t1 where
   d1.stringvalue='Where' and d1.id=Table.Col1 and d2.stringvalue='are' and d2.id=Table.Col2 and d3.id=Table.Col3;
```

The output which I expect from the above query is:

```
      you
```

Given col1=1 ('Where'), Col2=2 ('Are') I want to find out Col3's string value ('You')?

However, it turns out that for more complex queries this mapping from id to string turns out to be cumbersome. Is there some way by which the same query can be converted to a neat readable and short query in sql

Comment: Can you still elaborate your question clearly and post some sample output what you are expecting?

Comment: @SOaddict The output which I expect from the above query is "you"

Comment: @SOaddict I have tried to make my question clearer..i hope it helps. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select SUBSTRING(d2.stringvalue,5,7) AS "YOU" 
   from dictionary d1, dictionary d2, dictionary d3, Table t1
  where d1.stringvalue='Where' and
        d1.id=Table.Col1 and 
        SUBSTRING(d2.stringvalue,,3) ='are' and
        SUBSTRING(d2.stringvalue,5,7) ='you' and
        d2.id=Table.Col2 and 
        d3.id=Table.Col3;
```

If you just need "you" as output the above query should work.